# Django form not displaying Datepicker and Timepicker

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Hi Djangonauts,
                   I am new to Django. Please forgive any mistakes in code or logic. I am using *django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus* from the below repository to add a datepicker to my code.  https://github.com/monim67/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus. I have done a pip install. I have done `pip install django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus`. I have added this in my settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [    
    'bootstrap_datepicker_plus',
]
```

also added

```
BOOTSTRAP3 = {
    'include_jquery': True,
}
```

However it is not working. I have all my code below. I am also not able to add DecimalField and IntegerField in my form as that gives errors. But right now I am more focused on the Datepicker. I have attached images of how it should display and how it is displaying. What am I doing wrong here

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Event
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import DatePickerInput, TimePickerInput


class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    price: forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
    quantity: forms.IntegerField()
class Meta:
    model = Event
    fields = ('price', 'stock', 'date', 'time_from', 'time_to', 'event_choice')
    widgets = {
        'date': DatePickerInput(),
        'time_from': TimePickerInput(),
        'time_to': TimePickerInput(),

    }

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['stock'].label = "How many people can attend your event"
    self.fields['price'].label = "How much do members have to pay to attend"
    self.fields['event_choice'].label = "What kind of event is this?"
    self.fields['date'].label = "When do you plan to host your event"
    self.fields['time_from'].label = "What time does the event start"
    self.fields['time_to'].label = "What time does the event end"
```

**Template.html**

```
  {% extends 'base.html' %}
  {% block body %}
  {% load bootstrap3 %}
  {% block extrahead %}       {# Extra Resources Start #}
  {{ form.media }}            {# Form required JS and CSS #}
  {% endblock %}              {# Extra Resources End #}





<div class="form-group row">
     {{field.errors}}
     <form action="{% url 'event:new_event' slug=post.slug %}" method="post" >
         {% csrf_token %}
         {% bootstrap_form form %} 
         <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" />
     </form>
</div>
{% endblock  %}
```

**Models.py**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='seller')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='course')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.IntegerField((validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(35)]))
    date = models.DateField()
    time_from = models.TimeField()
    time_to = models.TimeField()
```

**Base.html**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

**This is how it should work**
[image]

**This is how it is now**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing bootstrap 3 and bootstrap 4.

1. In your base.html there is a css link to bootstrap 3.3.7 (I cannot see how this file is being used by your template.html file though)
2. In your settings.py file you are using BOOTSTRAP4
3. In your template.html file it states `{% load bootstrap3 %}`.

The documentation states `Use BOOTSTRAP3 if you are using Bootstrap 3` [[1]](https://github.com/monim67/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus), i.e. you should probably switch to BOOTSTRAP3 in your settings file.

Comment: Hi Mattias  I changed it to Bootstrap3 but I am still getting the same error. The template.html has a `{% block body %}` and `{% endblock %}` that gets the base.html in the template.html

Comment: To make use of the base.html file from template.html file you need to write {% extends 'base.html' %} in the top of template.html. Also you need to have a {% block base%}{% endblock%} in base.html at the position where you want the code to end up.

Comment: thank you that and some more edits to forms.py got the job done, Thank you so much. The fields and widgets have to treated separately. anything that says  "fields." does not work in the widgets and have to be kept separately